# Tivoli work scheduler -adding time delay after job dependency

Tags: tws, tivoli, tivoli-work-scheduler, tivoli-identity-manager

I need some help with TWS schedule definition.
I have JOB1 and JOB2. I want JOB2 to execute after success of JOB1 but after 30mins of its success. Is this feasible?

Something like this, what is the right format and syntax to achieve this

```
:
WORKLOAD-SERVER#JOB1

WORKLOAD-SERVER#JOB2
 FOLLOWS JOB1 + 30min
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible directly on the dependency, but you can achieve this result with an additional job (e.g. JOBWAIT) between JOB1 or JOB2.

JOBWAIT can do one of the following alternatives:

1. run a `sleep 1800` command. This is easier to implment, but the JOBWAIT will ABEND if there is an issue on the machine, e.g. is rebooted during the 30 min sleep.
2. calculate when JOB2 have to start as now + 30 mins (e.g. using datecalc), and add an AT dependency on JOB2 using conman/ocli or REST APIs. This is more complex to implement but JOBWAIT is short and won't be running for 30 mins.